# Is Oracle classes12 driver single threaded?

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, jdbc, driver

I use java spring application with 2 beans that use the same class. Difference only in url to Oracle database. One oracle server on my local computer, another on remote.
So there are 2 threads each connected to different Oracle host.
But I found that when I e.g. kill session on my local - to receive error message on client part about it, should wait untill finished execution of query on remote. 
Does it specific of Oracle classes12 driver? Or may be I should check code that I use?

Comment: The bug is in your code. Not in the Oracle driver. Without seeing your code and the stack trace of the exception you get, it's impossible to help.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using a 10 year - old version of Oracle JDBC driver?

Comment: What JDBC class is being shared between your two threads? What are you using to retrive the connection (a connection pool or DriverManager)?